# code not working - SetDwordValue not working in vbs

Tags: vbscript

Here is my code:

```
Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT= &H80000000
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER= &H80000001
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE= &H80000002
Const HKEY_USERS= &H80000003
Set StdOut = WScript.StdOut
Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Hardware Profiles\UnitedVideo\CONTROL\VIDEO\{D218E173-A430-11E8-80D8-005056C00008}\0001"
strValueName = "venkat"
oReg.SetDWordValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, 800
oReg.GetDWordValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, dval
WScript.Echo "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\"  & " = " &  dval
```

I'm running in Windows 10.

`SetDWordValue` of in the script is not working.
`GetDwordValue` is working fine and I'm getting the data.

Tried all the possibilities. Even the code from MSDN is not working. I want to change my registry key using vbs.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that you simply don't have permission to write to that registry key. The WMI registry methods don't raise an error when something goes wrong, so you need to check the method's return code, e.g. by changing the line

```
oReg.SetDWordValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, 800
```

to

```
rc = oReg.SetDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, 800)
WScript.Echo rc
```

A return code of 5 means you have a permission error.

To fix that you probably just need to run the script "as Admin".